# Can't add contents to file using file_put_contents

Tags: php

I'm outputting the contents of a file to another file, but the contents is just not being put into the second file. It creates the file but does not put the output to the file, it displays the output on the screen.

```
require_once 'templates/'.$layout.'/contact.php';
ob_start();
$content = ob_get_clean();

file_put_contents($dir.'/contact.php',$content);
chmod($dir.'/contact.php',0777);
```

The funny thing is when I do this file_put_contents($dir.'/contact.php','dsf'); it writes to the file, when doing file_put_contents($dir.'/contact.php',$content);
is does not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand... You include a file and then call ob_start() followed by an immediate ob_get_clean().

What is suppose to be in the ob_get_clean??

You should have:

```
ob_start(); //<--- Start the buffer

require_once 'templates/'.$layout.'/contact.php';

$content = ob_get_clean();

file_put_contents($dir.'/contact.php',$content);
chmod($dir.'/contact.php',0777);
```

Answer (score 0):

you might not have the rights to write to that file, or folder if you are creating that file

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 0 2009-10-07 17:20 contact.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 2009-10-07 17:19 8c492a19cfbb713f89d0946482c5ee42